# extjs4 combobox change also change another combobox datastore, and choose the value

Tags: combobox, extjs4, onchange, datastore

This might be a silly question, but I want to ask if there is a possibility to change another combobox's store data when a combobox selected value is changed.

It might be confusing, so let me give a clear example,...

comboboxA has a datastore that contains of country's name
comboboxB has a datastore that contains of city's name

so, the data in `comboboxA` could be:

```
 - USA 
 - Mexico
 - England
```

And the data in`comboboxB` when the value of `comboboxA` is "USA" would be:

```
 - Texas
 - New York
 - Washington
```

but when the value of comboboxA is "England", the data in comboboxB would be:

```
 - London
 - Manchester
```

How could I do that?

I've try:

```js
comboboxA.on("change", function(cb, newValue, oldValue){

    if(newValue == "USA"){
       comboboxB.store.loadData(["Texas", "New York", "Washington"]);
       comboboxB.setValue("Texas");
    }
    else if(newValue == "England"){
       comboboxB.store.loadData(["London", "Manchester"]);
       comboboxB.setValue("London");
    }

});
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the updated [Combobox FAQ](http://www.sencha.com/learn/combobox-faq/). You must use the listeners for the select event. See the example in "linked comboBoxes"

Answer (score -1):

Your data should be of the form:

```js
[ {cityName: "Texas"}, {cityName: "New York"}, {cityName: "Washington"} ]
```

And the store for comboboxB should have fields like:

```js
var storeB = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields : { 'cityName' },
    ...
});
```

But you did not say what the error was, so I can just guess if this could be your problem. You should come up with more details about what the problem is and how it shows up.